# NiFi Registry - Cannot able to restore the flow from Git Hub in NiFi 1.9.2

Tags: github, apache-nifi, apache-nifi-registry

We have followed the steps mentioned in below link for configuring the registry flow with Git Hub in window's environment

https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Community-Articles/Storing-Apache-NiFi-Versioned-Flows-in-a-Git-Repository/ta-p/248713

And its worked successfully, however we cannot able to restore the flow from the Git Hub, While doing so we are facing below issue:

**The Flow Registry with ID 1e6ef196-0170-1000-e788-b836ec0ea4a4 reports that no Flow exists with Bucket 5964ee6a-929a-4c0c-a169-c6d6183d1ac7, Flow e7721726-8c6a-4399-920d-e867683f6b92, Version 1**

[image]
Please help to resolve the reported issue.

Comment: have you pulled your source from git to nifi-registry?

Comment: yes and referred the location in registry provider.xml file @Lamanus